# Magento Category Products reindex error

Tags: php, database, magento

I recently upgraded a magento from 1.5 to 1.9 and everything is working except for reindexing of **Category Products**.

On the admin backend, I just get a general error that the process has failed.

so, I did it via command line using the `shell/indexer.php` and this is the output:

```
[www-data@DevServer shell]$ php -f indexer.php reindexall
Product Attributes index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:20
Product Prices index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:06
Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully in 00:02:59
Category Products index process unknown error:
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dev_salveo`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON )' in /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#7 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(49): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_categor...', Array, false)
#8 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_categor...', Array, false)
#9 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('catalog_categor...', 'catalog_categor...', false)
#10 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Indexer/Product.php(935): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#11 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product->reindexAll()
#12 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#13 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#14 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/shell/indexer.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#15 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/shell/indexer.php(215): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#16 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dev_salveo`.`catalog_category_product_index`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_CTGR_PRD_IDX_CTGR_ID_CAT_CTGR_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_category_entity` (`entity_id`) ON ), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product_index` (`category_id`, `product_id`, `position`, `is_parent`, `store_id`, `visibility`) SELECT `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`category_id`, `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`product_id`, `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`position`, `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`is_parent`, `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`store_id`, `catalog_category_product_index_idx`.`visibility` FROM `catalog_category_product_index_idx` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `category_id` = VALUES(`category_id`), `product_id` = VALUES(`product_id`), `position` = VALUES(`position`), `is_parent` = VALUES(`is_parent`), `store_id` = VALUES(`store_id`), `visibility` = VALUES(`visibility`)' in /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235
Stack trace:
#0 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...')
#6 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Helper/Mysql4.php(49): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromSelect(Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_categor...', Array, false)
#7 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(153): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Helper_Mysql4->insertData(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product), Object(Varien_Db_Select), 'catalog_categor...', Array, false)
#8 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Resource/Abstract.php(113): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->insertFromTable('catalog_categor...', 'catalog_categor...', false)
#9 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Category/Indexer/Product.php(935): Mage_Index_Model_Resource_Abstract->syncData()
#10 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer/Abstract.php(143): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Indexer_Product->reindexAll()
#11 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(212): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer_Abstract->reindexAll()
#12 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Process.php(260): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexAll()
#13 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/shell/indexer.php(167): Mage_Index_Model_Process->reindexEverything()
#14 /home/www-data/dev.my-domain.co.uk/public_html/shell/indexer.php(215): Mage_Shell_Compiler->run()
#15 {main}
Catalog Search Index index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:24
Stock Status index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Tag Aggregation Data index was rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

Any idea what this error means? how can I fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error is because of missing category id or product id in entity tables.
When trying to run the Category Products index, and is due to the indexing process attempting to insert a row into the catalog_category_product_index table, where either the product_id or the category_id don't exist. This causes the "Intergrity Constraint Violation".

This can sometimes happen when a database gets corrupt while upgrading from lower version.

Use following function to update your tables:

```
require_once 'abstract.php';
class Fix_Shell_Index_Table_Repair extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{

    /**
     *
     * @return Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface
     */
    protected function _getConnection()
    {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        return $writeConnection;
    }

    /**
     *Delete catalog product relation table data.
     */
    protected function _processTableData()
    {

        $this->_getConnection()->query('delete from `catalog_category_product` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from `catalog_product_entity`);');
        echo "catalog_category_product table repaired\n";

        $this->_getConnection()->query('delete from `catalog_category_product` WHERE category_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_category_entity); ');
        echo "catalog_category_product table repaired\n";

        $this->_getConnection()->query('delete from `catalog_product_website` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); ');
        echo "catalog_product_website table repaired\n";

        $this->_getConnection()->query('delete from `catalog_product_index_eav_idx` WHERE entity_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); ');
        echo "catalog_product_index_eav_idx table repaired\n";

        $this->_getConnection()->query('delete from `catalog_product_index_eav` WHERE entity_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); ');
        echo "catalog_product_index_eav table repaired\n";

        $this->_getConnection()->query('delete from `catalog_product_link` WHERE product_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity); ');
        echo "catalog_product_link table repaired\n";

        $this->_getConnection()->query('delete from `catalog_product_relation` WHERE parent_id not in(select entity_id from catalog_product_entity);');
        echo "catalog_product_relation table repaired\n";

        $this->_getConnection()->query('DELETE from `sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` WHERE `address_id` not in(select `address_id` from `sales_flat_quote_address`);');
        echo "sales_flat_quote_shipping_rate table repaired\n";

        echo "All done\n";
    }

    /**
     * Run script
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        try {
            $this->_processTableData();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }

    }
}

$shell = new Fix_Shell_Index_Table_Repair();
$shell->run();
```

Comment: Spot on! I ran the following [queries](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ZYKzJxnz) (taken from your answer) in phpMyAdmin and it re-indexed :)